# Using csv data in print composer

Tags: qgis, csv

I want to present data from a csv-file in a fact box next to a map. The map is created using QGIS (2.12.2) print composer. The data in the csv-file is updated regularly and I want to be able to link to the contents of it 
by using an expression so that the data within can be presented as part of a text or in a table using a html rendering.

The file looks more or less like this:

```
zone,area    
2,901403    
1,109706    
n,5061049    
V,587821
```

I want to do this for a simple map. How can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

**1. Add the csv data using "add delimited text layer";**

In the options make sure you:

- Set the field delimiters;
- Set geometry to No Geometry;
- Check the watch file;

**2a (single line) Use created layer as coverage for atlas in composer**

If you only have one line in your csv file, you can do the folowing.
In the composer, in the atlas tab use you csv layer as coverage layer.

This way you can use "Fields and Values" from the csv layer to create your expression.

**2a (multiple lines) Add attribute table item in composer**

Since you want to add multiple lines in your composer, all you need is to add a attribute table item to your coposition.

Notice that you can use expressions in a column, in case you want to compound a few fields in one phrase and remove the outline to make it look like a text instead a table.

Comment: Nice solution using the layer as a coverage for an atlas. But a bit like a hack since it only works on one-liners. I am looking for a solution to present multi-line content from a multi.line csv-file. It is therefore necessary to iterate through all lines and present them in a simple map (not an atlas).

Comment: What about replacing step 2 above with just adding an attribute table into the composer, and setting it to show the imported delimited text layer?

Comment: In that case, all you need is the attribute table item.